# How can I solve my USB port malfunction in my HP DV6 Laptop?

Tags: usb-storage

I have currently 4 USB ports in my HP DV6 1337tx Laptop. Everything was fine until before someday when I saw my pendrive is being detected and within 3-4 seconds it is being undetected again. That thing happened to only a particular port. I use 3G modem to access internet. At the same port I see the same problem. Now the port is taking any pendrive correctly. But my modem is continuously detected and undetected by the very same port saying "No Device". So I stopped using that particular port and everything is fine as of now. Now I see another problem arising that some particular pendrives are not being detected by any of my ports but they are detected by other laptops.

So all in all I see all of my pendrive ports are malfunctioning very badly. So how can I "reset" them back to work fine as they did before?

Comment: did you unplug the thumb drive before ejecting it?

Comment: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/14711-usb-flash-drive-not-detected-in-windows#solution

Comment: @jjj, tried. No help!

Comment: When you say they "are not being detected", what precisely do you mean? Do you get the "bee-booop" sound? Do they show up in the Device Manager? Do they show up in Disk Management?

Comment: In case of pendrives, which are not detected, I can not hear a single sound and no icon for detection of storage device is seen in the taskbar!