# Why is no new driver being installed successfully in my computer?

Tags: drivers

The problem is no new driver is being installed in my laptop when attached. Usually when a new pendrive is connected, the driver of that pendrive is installed in the laptop (it shows a "installing driver" window then). But now no new driver is being installed successfully in my laptop when a new device is attached. So the pendrive is not detected naturally. Also, today I bought a [MBlaze device](http://www.mtsindia.in/mblaze/index.html) and connected it. The same problem happened this time too and a message came saying I have to install the drivers manually. So how can I solve this problem?

My OS is Windows 7 and the same MBlaze device installed successfully on my bother's Windows 7 laptop without downloading the drivers from the manufacturer's site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I solve my USB port malfunction in my HP DV6 Laptop?](http://superuser.com/questions/517739/how-can-i-solve-my-usb-port-malfunction-in-my-hp-dv6-laptop)

Answer (score 0):

These days most USB storage devices don't need any driver to function.

What OS are you using?

Regarding the MBlaze device (I am not sure what it is, it's unfamiliar to me), there is no way Windows would automatically install driver for it, you have to install the driver and its utility software manually which should be provided by manufacturer. Windows just don't always have the solution for all hardware device drivers.

Comment: I am using windows 7 and the same Mblaze device is succesfully installed in my brother's win7 laptop.

Comment: MBlaze is a USB device for doing broadband internet from [MTS](http://www.mtsindia.in)

Comment: The first sentence is false. Mass storage devices require driver, but it's included with Windows. OP wrote that his OS doesn't install any driver, including this one.

Comment: @gronostaj is right - Windows might not need to download any manufacturer-specific drivers for mass storage devices, but that does not mean no drivers are required at all.